# When I was disabling the SQL job, it has gone missing

Tags: sql, jobs

When I was disabling a specific SQL server 2012 job it has gone missing. Definitely I haven't deleted this job - if I would have hit the delete option accidently, then it will ask to confirm the deletion. 
Can this happen? We have tried to see this job from the sa login, also checked the sysjobs but still couldn't find. I don't think the audit was enabled on the SQL server too.
Is there any slightest possibility for this to happen?
Thanks

Comment: check whether that was renamed as blank

Comment: There weren't any entries in sysjobs with suspicious names or blank. Is there any specific location I can check this please?

Comment: check your audit history

Comment: unfortunately audit history wasn't on :(